# FOR Cycle inside a UDF in Excel not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently programming an Excel Function which should return the average of the last 5 non-empty positions of an array. To do that I want to go through the array while inside the function as follows:

```
Function AVERAGE_LAST_5(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim x As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, sum As Integer
    Dim myArr() As Variant

    myArr() = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng))
    x = rng.Count
    i = 0:: j = 0:: sum = 0

    For i = x To 1 Step -1

        If myArr(x).Value <> 0 Then
            sum = sum + myArr(x)
            j = j + 1
        Else
        End If

        If j = 5 Then Stop
        x = x - 1

    Next

    AVERAGE_LAST_5 = sum / 5

End Function
```

**Problem:** the `for` loop doesn't work, when reaching the first `if` the program aborts.

Does anyone has had the same problem?
Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Your function fails on If myArr(x).Value <> 0 Then because .Value is not a property of the array myArr, it is a property of a Range object

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks the reply it solved the problem :) ;)

Answer (score 0):

myarr will be a two-dimensional array, and not a range.  You will need to provide both dimensions:

```
If isarray(myarr) then
for i = ubound(myarr,1) to lbound(myarr,1) step -1
    for j = ubound(myarr,2) to lbound (myarr,2) step -1
       if myarr(i,j) <> 0 then
           K=k+1
           Mysum = mysum + myarr(I,j)
        Endif
    Next j
Next i
Else ‘ single value
    mysum =myarr(I,j)
Endif
```

Answer (score 0):

## Arrays Are Faster

### Final Version (Hopefully)

This version additionally has the `NumberOfLastValues` argument (**Required**) so you can choose how many values will be summed up and it is shortened with the `GoSub...Return` statement since the `If` statement is the same for by rows and by columns.
For some other details look in the First Version below.

### Usage

**In VBA**:

```
Sub LastAverage()
  Debug.Print AvgLast(Range("B4:G14"), 5)
End Sub
```

**In Excel**:

```
=AvgLast(B4:G14,5)
```

---

```
Function AvgLast(SearchRange As Range, ByVal NumberOfLastValues As Long, _
    Optional ByVal Row_0_Column_1 As Integer = 0) As Double

  Dim vntRange As Variant   ' Range Array

  Dim i As Long             ' Range Array Rows Counter
  Dim j As Integer          ' Range Array Columns Counter
  Dim k As Long             ' Values Counter
  Dim dblSum As Double      ' Values Accumulator

  If SearchRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

  vntRange = SearchRange.Value

  If Row_0_Column_1 = 0 Then
    ' By Row
    For i = UBound(vntRange) To 1 Step -1
      For j = UBound(vntRange, 2) To 1 Step -1
        GoSub Calc
      Next
    Next
   Else
    ' By Column
    For j = UBound(vntRange, 2) To 1 Step -1
      For i = UBound(vntRange) To 1 Step -1
        GoSub Calc
      Next
    Next
  End If

TiDa:
  If k > 0 Then
    AvgLast = dblSum / k
  End If
Exit Function

Calc:
  If vntRange(i, j) <> "" And IsNumeric(vntRange(i, j)) Then
    k = k + 1
    dblSum = dblSum + vntRange(i, j)
    If k = NumberOfLastValues Then GoTo TiDa
  End If
Return

End Function
```

### First Version

It will return the average if there is at least 1 value and at most 5 values, otherwise it will return 0.

The Row_0_Column_1 arguments parameter is by default 0 and means that the search is done by row (first loop). If it is 1, then the search is done by column (second loop).

The basics are that the range is pasted (depsited) into an array and then the array is searched for existing 'numeric' values and not "" values that are summed up and when reaching the fifth value it 'jumps' out of the loop and divides the sum by 5.

---

```
Function AvgLast5(SearchRange As Range, Optional Row_0_Column_1 As Integer = 0) _
    As Double

  Dim vntRange As Variant   ' Range Array

  Dim i As Long             ' Range Array Rows Counter
  Dim j As Integer          ' Range Array Columns Counter
  Dim k As Long             ' Values Counter
  Dim dblSum As Double      ' Values Accumulator

  If SearchRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

  vntRange = SearchRange.Value

  If Row_0_Column_1 = 0 Then
    ' By Row
      For i = UBound(vntRange) To 1 Step -1
        For j = UBound(vntRange, 2) To 1 Step -1
          If vntRange(i, j) <> "" And IsNumeric(vntRange(i, j)) Then
            k = k + 1
            dblSum = dblSum + vntRange(i, j)
            If k = 5 Then GoTo TiDa
          End If
        Next
      Next
    Else
    ' By Column
      For j = UBound(vntRange, 2) To 1 Step -1
        For i = UBound(vntRange) To 1 Step -1
          If vntRange(i, j) <> "" And IsNumeric(vntRange(i, j)) Then
            k = k + 1
            dblSum = dblSum + vntRange(i, j)
            If k = 5 Then GoTo TiDa
          End If
        Next
      Next
  End If

TiDa:

  If k > 0 Then
    AvgLast5 = dblSum / k
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Hi VBasic2008, thanks for your answer.
The array I'm using is pretty simple, it is a row with 30 values, myArr(30). 
The user should enter a 1 row Range which I convert to a onedimentional array. 
(I will post a picture right away)

Comment: What is the problem with my functions? BTW When you 'paste' a range into an array e.g. 'vntRange = rng', the array is automatically two dimensional even with one row or only column only, but it is much faster than looping through the range.

Comment: Hi VBasic2008, your function just evaluates the last 5 values of the Range, I need to check the last 5 non-empty positions. Thanks though:

Comment: @Rafael Figueiras: I don't think so. The result is different if you choose by row or by column. You might have made the wrong choice. And in which version did you notice the fault?

Comment: @Rafael Figueiras: In your example you have to choose by row or simply omit the parameter e.g. for the first version =AvgLast5(A1:P1) or for the final version =AvgLast(A1:P1,5).

Comment: let me test again :)

Comment: @Rafael Figueiras: I'm sorry, I think there is something wrong with the first version, but you are using it wrong: 22 is the row so it should be by row. But you can use the final version like this: =AvgLast(D22:AG22;5)

Comment: @Rafael Figueiras: My example might have confused you, but my example is a multirow and multicolumn range. When you're  looking in a row, use by row (0) or omitted.

Comment: still can't get it working :/

https://ibb.co/njRWRZs

I've just seen you last comment, let me test again :)

Comment: @Rafael Figueiras: The first version definitely calculates wrongly. So use the final one.

Comment: still cant get it workig properly:

https://ibb.co/ZddR0Fd

Will check it further tomorow

Answer (score 0):

after a couple of tough days at work I've finally got some time to improve my function taking your tips on board.

I've made some changes to enable the function to deal either with 1-Row or 1-Column Ranges. Basic Error handling was also added and a function discripton is as well available (under the FX Excel button).

Feel free to comment and/or use the code. 
Here the result:

```
Function AVERAGE_LAST_N(rng As Range, N As Integer)

Dim NrN As Integer, NrR As Integer, NrC As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim sum As Double
Dim myArr As Variant

    NrN = rng.Count           'Number of array positions
    NrR = rng.Rows.Count      'Number of Rows in the array
    NrC = rng.Columns.Count   'Number of Rows in the array
    i = 0:: j = 0:: sum = 0   'Counters

    '####################################################'
    '## Transpose Range into array if row or if column ##'
    '####################################################'

          If rng.Rows.Count > 1 And rng.Columns.Count = 1 Then             'Transpose a Column Range into an Array
               myArr = Application.Transpose(rng)

          ElseIf rng.Rows.Count = 1 And rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then         'Transpose a Row Range into an Array
              myArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng))

          ElseIf rng.Rows.Count > 1 And rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then         'Retunrs an Error if Range is a Matrix *ERR_002*
              AVERAGE_LAST_N = "ERR_002"
              Exit Function

          End If

    '####################################################'
    '## Transpose Range into array if row or if column ##'
    '####################################################'


    '################'
    '## Start Main ##'
    '################'

          For i = NrN To 1 Step -1
               If IsNumeric(myArr(NrN)) Then
                    sum = sum + myArr(NrN)
                    j = j + 1

               End If

               If j = N Then Exit For

               NrN = NrN - 1

          Next

          AVERAGE_LAST_N = sum / N

    '##############'
    '## End Main ##'
    '##############'


    '####################'
    '## Error Debuging ##'
    '####################'

          If j < N Then
              AVERAGE_LAST_N = "ERR_001"
              Exit Function
          End If

    '####################'
    '## Error Debuging ##'
    '####################'

End Function

Sub DescribeFunction()

   Dim FuncName As String
   Dim FuncDesc As String
   Dim Category As String
   Dim ArgDesc(1) As String

   FuncName = "AVERAGE_LAST_N"
   FuncDesc = "Returns the average of the last N non-empty values in the selected Range"
   Category = 14 'Text category
   ArgDesc(0) = "Range that contains the values" & Chr(10) & _
               "ERR_001 - There are not enought non-empty or null values in the range" & Chr(10) & _
               "ERR_002 - Selected range is a matrix and not a row or column range"

   ArgDesc(1) = "Dimention of the sample" & Chr(10) & _
               "ERR_001 - There are not enought non-empty or null values in the range" & Chr(10) & _
               "ERR_002 - Selected range is a matrix and not a row or column range"

   Application.MacroOptions _
       Macro:=FuncName, _
       Description:=FuncDesc, _
       Category:=Category, _
       ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgDesc

End Sub


'#######################################################################################

'                   ###############################################
'                   #############      Error DB      ##############
'                   ###############################################
'
'
'    ERR_001 - There are not enought non-empty values in the range
'    ERR_002 - Selected range is a matrix and not a row or column range
'
```

Rafa